# Is it possible to get an "offset" of a string in a file at a reasonably fast speed?

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

In HTML5, it's easy to slice a (huge) file if I know start byte and end byte:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var blob = file.slice(start, end);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

But what if I want to slice a huge text file from String A to String B? I don't know where those start/end bytes will be! If I try to place content of the whole file in a single string and extract content using `event.target.result.slice(event.target.result.indexOf("stringA"), event.target.result.indexOf("stringB"))`, oh, no... it doesn't look good...
So, is it possible to write a function which will return value indicating an "offset" (byte) of a selected string in a file? (This function must return array consisting of multiple values if a string is not unique in a file).

Comment: Was your first attempt too slow?

Comment: Well, of course, if I try to manipulate with several-hundreds-MB-long string... the browser won't like this. It may even crash.